# Cloud Function is not triggering my client-side function

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In our project, we activated cloud functions and deployed a function into the cloud to notify all the clients whenever a Remote Config value has changed on firebase remote config.

**Cloud function:**

```
    exports.pushConfig = functions.remoteConfig.onUpdate(versionMetadata => {
    // Create FCM payload to send data message to PUSH_RC topic.

    const payload = {
        topic: "PUSH_RC",
        data: {
            "CONFIG_STATE": "STALE"
        }
    };
    // Use the Admin SDK to send the ping via FCM.
    return admin.messaging().send(payload, false).then(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        return null;
    });
});
```

And I also have done everything mentioned in
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image

But still, when I update a key on remote config, I can see that the function is triggered by the firebase from the cloud function logs, but it won't call my client-side function, which is registered to messaging.

Comment: There's *a lot* going on here, which makes it harder for people to help. Can you reproduce the same problem by calling `admin.messaging().send(...)` in a local Node.js script? If so, you ruled out Remote Config and Cloud Functions as possible causes and can focus on analyzing FCM message delivery.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I have started emulators with the command of "firebase emulators:start" and then it printed 2 warnings :

Comment: ⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, firestore, database, hosting, pubsub, storage"

⚠  Your requested "node" version "14" doesn't match your global version "17"

Comment: Using the emulators adds yet another complex component to the problem. What I meant is whether you can create a simple local `send.js` script that calls the Admin SDK's `admin.messaging().send`, and then reproduce the problem locally with `node send.js`?